# 301 Redirection in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect a URL, using the following line in a .htaccess file:

```
redirect 301 /old_file_path /new_file_path
```

Redirection is working fine but the URL that I get is in a different format:

```
/new_file_path/?/old_file_path
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Using the `Redirect` directive alone like this should not be able to produce that effect in the first place. And what does PHP have to do with this?

Comment: Use an HTTP protocol/folder/file as the 2nd argument, not a system path. Ref: http://www.apache.com/how-to-redirect-pages-using-a-301-redirect-and-the-htaccess-file/

Comment: Is this your full code for it? There seems to be parts missing. Also, which OS is this running off of?

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^/old_file_path(.*)$ /new_file_path$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Oh, my bad. Code that I used is this:
redirect 301 /old_file_path /new_file_path

Old URL: https://www.keleven.com/master-trainer/
New URL: https://www.keleven.com/master_trainer_course/

URL that I get: https://www.keleven.com/master_trainer_course/?/master-trainer/

Comment: @ShipraSinha You need to edit your post instead. We can't see the actual syntax in comments.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Just did

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51611919/edit < that edits your question, which is what I meant, not the comment you left @ShipraSinha you were given answers also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the Example below:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html
Redirect 301 /oldpage2.html http://www.yoursite.com/folder/
```

or share you full .htaccess file so we can better take a look.

Make sure mod_rewrite apachi module is on.

I tested the code at my end and it is working fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 302 /master-trainer https://www.keleven.com/master_trainer_course
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: `redirect 301 /master-trainer https://www.keleven.com/master_trainer_course`
This is what I used

Comment: it suppose to work fine I test on my local host and it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect to the complete new path:

```
redirect 301 /old_file_path https://example.com/new_file_path
```

Comment: There must be a way without hard-coding the server path